# 2つ以上のクラスで共通して1つの変数を使いたい

Tags: python, python3

`hoge`と`huga`という2つのクラスのそれぞれのメソッドで数字`num`を共有して使いたいです。どのようにすれば2つのクラスのメソッドで共通して使えるでしょうか？
グローバル変数を使うべきでしょうか？

```
class hoge():
  def foo(self):
    print(num) # Error

class huga():
  def bar(self):
    print(num) # Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2つのオプションがあります：

- クラスでオブジェクトを開始してから、そのオブジェクトで目的のメソッドを呼び出します
- 使用する [@classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) 関数をクラスメソッドに変換するには

例:

```
class A(object):
    
    def a1(self):
        print(num)

    @classmethod
    def a2(cls):
        """ This a classmethod. """
        print "Hello from class A"

class B(object):
    def b1(self):
        print A().a1() # => prints 'Hello from an instance of A'
        print A.a2() # => 'Hello from class A'
```

または、必要に応じて継承を使用します

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 42

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print foo.x

a = Foo()
b = Bar(a)
```

Comment: クラスメソッドを使った方法のコードがまちがっていませんか？ a1() が未定義のような気がするのです

Comment: ああ、すみません、変数名が混同されました。コードを修正しました。